# How can I change the layout reactively using input button in Shiny App?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create my first Shiny App and I'm trying basically to get the App to plot two simple histograms, but with an Input Button get the user to choose if he wants to see the two histograms side by side (Horizontally) or one below the other (Vertically).

I tried to write the code below more as an attempt to explain my thought process to you than actually hoping it would work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
radioButtons('layout', 'Layout:', choices=c('Vertically', 'Horizontally'), inline=TRUE),
sliderInput(inputId = "num",
          label = "Choose a number",
          value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
plotOutput("hist1"),
plotOutput("hist2"))

server <- function(input,output) {

if (input$layout == "Horizontally") {
  output$hist1<-fluidRow(
  column(3,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(input$num)))))
  output$hist2<-column(3,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(input$num))))
} 
else if (input$layout == "Vertically") {
  output$hist1<-fluidRow(
    column(3,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(input$num)))))
  output$hist2<-fluidRow(
    column(3,plotOutput(hist(rnorm(input$num)))))
}

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `renderUI` to create the layout depending of the input, and `uiOutput` to display the result:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons('layout', 'Layout:', choices=c('Vertically', 'Horizontally'), inline=TRUE),
  sliderInput(inputId = "num",
              label = "Choose a number",
              value = 25, min = 1, max = 100),
  uiOutput("plots"))

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$hist1<-renderPlot(hist(rnorm(input$num)))
  output$hist2<-renderPlot(hist(rnorm(input$num)))
  output$plots<-renderUI(if (input$layout == "Horizontally") {
    fluidRow(column(3,plotOutput("hist1")),
             column(3,plotOutput("hist2")))
    } 
    else if (input$layout == "Vertically") {
      fluidRow(plotOutput("hist1"),plotOutput("hist2"))
      })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Considering always displaying things side by side, would there be a way to instead choose through the input button if I want to display only 1 histogram or both?

Comment: Yes, just change the content of the renderUI to adapt to your need